# VBA / Selenium - Trigger an onchange event

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, onchange

Using  seleniumbasics I’m trying to trigger an onchange event on the code bellow:

```
ChromoLink.FindElementById("notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor").SendKeys  (onchange)
```

But, for some reason it’s not seting fire on the field, so here is some java:

```html
<input type="text" name="notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor" size="15%" id="notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor" bindingReference="entity.promocaoPK.cdFornecedor" value="" formatType="NUMBER" formato="5" obrigatorio="true" rotulo="Fornecedor" allowZero="true" desformataOnSubmit="false" onkeypress="CN_KPS(this, event);" onblur="CN_BLR(this);" onkeydown="CN_KDN(this, event);" onmousemove="CN_MMOV(this, event);" onmouseout="CN_MOUT(this, event);" onmouseover="CN_MOV(this, event);" onfocus="CN_OFC(this, event);" onchange="IS_request('credorSomenteFornecedorComInputSelectHandler','/AjaxServlet.ajax', 'consCredorSomenteFornecedor', 'notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor', this.value,'/sienge','spjGenericSearch.do?spwProxySearchURL=%2F%2FsearchCredorSomenteFornecedor.jsp&moduleName=%2FCAD', 'null', 'Consulta de Fornecedores','400','700', '&bind_entity.promocaoPK.cdFornecedor=notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor&bind_entity.credor.nmCredor=notaFiscalCad.credor.nmCredor', 'false', event, 'InputSelectAutoComplete', '','false'); " style="width:100%" id="notaFiscalCad.cdFornecedor" input-select="consCredorSomenteFornecedor" idIframe=""></td>
```

Comment: Is the url public? Typically selenium is pretty good at triggering event listeners when all the required actions are performed in the correct sequence. Are you sure you have addressed all the requirements? E.g. any other event listeners? Also, you can still resort to execute_script and pass in the function call from the onchange.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your tip @QHarr...it's done:

```
ChromoLink.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('nmDocumento').onchange"
```